# Why are hybrid orbitals more efficient at overlapping?

Tags: bond, valence-bond-theory

What is the reason for considering that hybrid orbitals provide more effective overlapping resulting in formation of stronger bonds?

Will this reasoning be correct that the hybrid orbitals have larger and smaller lobes than pure orbitals?

Comment: It is not so much about the size of the lobes but more about the direction. Hybrid orbitals usually have an orientation that allows them to overlap with the orbitals of their bonding partner much better, i.e. in a head-on manner.

Comment: Hybrid orbitals exist only in our head. It would be wrong to perceive an atom as a kind of amoeba which grows this or that kind of pseudopods (=orbitals) as it sees fit.